# How to improve the efficiency of a code in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of `Pe` of shape `(5100,5100)`. I am trying to find the neighbor indices using the code below but for this shape of `Pe`, the computational time is 100 seconds. Is there a more time efficient way to do it?

```
def get_neighbor_indices(position, dimensions):
    '''
    dimensions is a shape of np.array
    '''
    i, j = position
    indices = [(i+1,j), (i-1,j), (i,j+1), (i,j-1)]
    return [
        (i,j) for i,j in indices
        if i>=0 and i<dimensions[0]
            and j>=0 and j<dimensions[1]
        ]

def iterate_array(init_i, init_j, arr, condition_func):
    '''
    arr is an instance of np.array
    condition_func is a function (value) => boolean
    '''
    indices_to_check = [(init_i,init_j)]
    checked_indices = set()
    result = []
    t0 = None
    t1 = None
    timestamps = []
    while indices_to_check:
        pos = indices_to_check.pop()
        if pos in checked_indices:
            continue
        item = arr[pos]
        checked_indices.add(pos)
        if condition_func(item):
            result.append(item)
            t1=time.time()
            if(t0==None):
                t0=t1
            timestamps.append(t1-t0)
            indices_to_check.extend(
                get_neighbor_indices(pos, arr.shape)
            )
    return result,timestamps


Visited_Elements,timestamps=iterate_array(0,0, Pe, lambda x : x < Pin0)
```

Comment: Is the order of the `result` list important and if so, why? Are the timestamps important (instead of the overall time spent for the whole process) and if so, why?

Comment: The order of the ```result``` list can be in any form. The ```timestamps``` are not important.

Comment: Python is really not well suited for such a computationally-intensive function. It is meant to be mainly used for writing script and/or glue codes. The standard implementation of Python is CPython which is a slow *interpreter*. JIT compiler can speed this up a bit but this is hard to make it fast due to Python being a very dynamic language and the generic lambda does not help. Your `get_neighbor_indices` function needs to allocate >20 Python objects and collect them using reference counting, which is pretty expensive. Consider using a native language like C/C++ where this can be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `scipy` and a slight change in the way the filter condition is described this can be made rather fast:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import label
import time

def collect_array(init_i, init_j, arr, condition_arr):
    t0=time.time()
    if not condition_arr[init_i, init_j]:
        return [], time.time() - t0
    
    islands = label(condition_arr)[0]
    mask = islands != islands[init_i, init_j]
    mx = np.ma.masked_array(Pe, mask)
    return mx.compressed(), time.time() - t0


# Trying it out
Pe = np.random.rand(5100, 5100)
Pin0 = 0.7

Visited_Elements, timestamp = collect_array(0,0, Pe, Pe < Pin0)

print(Visited_Elements,timestamp)
```

The core of the code is the [`label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html) function and the fact that the condition function is replaced by a boolean array.